# keep checkboxes checked after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, state, checkbox, persist

I have a couple of checkboxes. when any of them are clickd/checked and the search button is clicked, will grab their values and pass to the url as querystring and refresh the page returning results matching the passed query values.
like this: mysite.com/result.aspx?k="Hospital" OR "Office" OR "Emergency"

I am able to grab the values after 'k='. I have "Hospital" OR "Office" OR "Emergency" captured and stored in a variable. Now I need to reset the checked state of checkboxes based on these values after the page reloads and forgets the previous state of the controls. I couldn't move any further than this. Can someone help me?

```
  var checkedOnes=decodeURI(location.href.match(/\&k\=(.+)/)[1]);
        if (value.length == 2) {
            $('input[name="LocType"][value="' + value[1] + '"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
```

---

This is how I am capturing the checkboxes values and passing to the URL:

```
var checkboxValues = $("input[name=LocType]:checked").map(function() {
        return "\"" + $(this).val() + "\"";}).get().join(" OR ");

    window.location= url+checkboxValues;
```

---

```
    <div class="LocTypeChkBoxesSearch">
    <div class="LocTypeChkBoxes">
        <input name="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Hospital"/>HOSPITALS&#160;&#160;
        <input name="LocType" type="checkbox"  value="Office"/>  PHYSICIAN OFFICES&#160;&#160;
        <input name="LocType" type="checkbox"  value="Emergency"/>EMERGENCY CENTERS&#160;&#160;
        <input name="LocType" type="checkbox"  value="Out-Patient"/>OUT-PATIENT CENTERS&#160;&#160;
        <input name="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Facility"/>FACILITIES
    </div>
    <div class="searchBtnHolder"><a class="searchButton" href="#" type="submit" ><span>GO</span></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you considered using localStorage instead ?

Comment: not all browsers support html5 yet??!!

Comment: Check up on cookies, you are going to have to actually save them somewhere it would seem to me, and since you indicate server side is out, session is not an option it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same problem, and my solution is HTML5 Local Storage.
Add an function for colect checkboxes values

```
function(){
var data = $('input[name=checkboxName]:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    localStorage['data']=JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

And onload function to check checkboxes

```
function(){
    if(localStorage&&localStorage["data"]){
        var localStoredData=JSON.parse(localStorage["data"]);
        var checkboxes=document.getElementsByName('checkboxName');
        for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<localStoredData.length;j++){
                if(checkboxes[i].value==localStoredData[j]){
                    checkboxes[i].checked=true;
                }
            }
        }
        localStorage.removeItem('data');
    }
}
```

It's work fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
//Split the url parameter value and get all the values in an array
var checkedOnes = decodeURI(location.href.match(/\&k\=(.+)/)[1]).split(" OR ");

//Find all the checkbox with name="LocType" and cache them in local variable
var $checkBoxes = $('input[name=LocType]');

//Loop through the array and find the corresponding checkbox element using filter
$.each(checkedOnes, function(i, val){
    $checkBoxes.filter('value=[' + $.trim(val.replace(/\"/g, '')) +']').prop('checked', true);
});
```

I am splitting the value of `k` by `OR` which will give all the values in an array. Next, loop through the array and find the corresponding checkbox by matching its value attribute and set its `checked` property to `true` using `prop` method.

Comment: How is this gonna get all checkboxes unless you have this variable inside an 'each' function?var $checkBoxes = $('input[name=LocType]');

Comment: You don't have to keep it inside `each` loop. The reason I kept it outside and cached the result into a variable is to avoid finding all the checkboxes again and again in the loop.

Comment: This whole logic has to be inside document.ready() ??Its not working. I know I am  close..  :(

Comment: Can you check what is the value of `checkedOnes` before running the `each` loop?

Comment: Make sure you are running this code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..})` so that the elements are available before you try to find and set them `checked`.

Comment: "Emergency","Out-Patient","Office" etc is how checkedOnes will have values stored as..does that make difference??

Comment: Check my edited answer. Taken care of enclosing double quotes.

Comment: You should not send the enclosing double quotes along with the url, then you don't have to do anything while reading and setting the checkboxes.

Comment: No, not really :( It is really tricky to do this kind of thing client side, isn't it?? if i had access to server side code, i could have done this in a couple of minutes..

Comment: But you have to do everything on the client side so this is the best way to do.

Comment: $.trim(val.replace(/\"/g, '')) +']')--------> is this trimming the double quotes??

Comment: `val.replace(/\"/g, '')` will replace `"` by empty string and then `$.trim()` will remove any white spaces around the string.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need JavaScript for this. You can check the $_GET parameters in your back-end code, and serve the page with the proper form element attributes.

In PHP, for example:

```
<input name="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Facility" <?php if (isset($_GET['LocType'] && $_GET['LocType'] == 'Facility') { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> /> FACILITIES
```